# Get the actual NSData from ALAsset (Everytime I get bigger image size)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

What I'm trying to do is getting NSData from ALAsset (Image), The size of the image on the disk is 75 KB but when I'm trying to get the NSData from that asset it returns NSData with very bigger size, My question is "How to return the 75KB data not the bigger size from the image"

My code:

```
ALAssetRepresentation* representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
CGFloat scale  = 1;
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullResolutionImage]
                                             scale:scale orientation:orientation];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Comment: Perhaps you want the JPEG representation instead of PNG.

Comment: How are you getting that 75KB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**iOS 9 Update:** In iOS 9 and later, you should use `requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler:` on `PHImageManager` since the following code uses deprecated methods.

---

Did you look at the "[Getting Raw Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009728-CH1-SW11)" section in the Class Reference?

```
ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);

// add error checking here
NSUInteger buffered = [representation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
NSData *sourceData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
```

Comment: warning about this method; It is really good method as memory wise. But if you use this method images will lose their orientation. (every image will be landscape regardless their orientation). I am trying to find a way but so far no result